# MySql query accumlate count for each record before the time point of the record in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table to store student attendance with a date time,
I would like to find out for each record the accumulative attendance count before the time at that record.

Below is the original table:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|id| sid |  IsAttend  |  DateTime   |
-------------------------------------
| 1|  1  |     1      |  2020-01-01 |
| 2|  2  |     0      |  2020-01-01 |
| 3|  1  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |
| 4|  2  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |
| 5|  3  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |
| 6|  1  |     0      |  2019-12-25 |
| 7|  3  |     1      |  2019-12-25 |
| 8|  1  |     1      |  2019-12-20 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And below is what I want:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|id| sid |  IsAttend  |  DateTime   | a_count |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1|  1  |     1      |  2020-01-01 |    2    |
| 2|  2  |     0      |  2020-01-01 |    1    |
| 3|  1  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |    1    |
| 4|  2  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |    0    |
| 5|  3  |     1      |  2019-12-31 |    1    |
| 6|  1  |     0      |  2019-12-25 |    1    |
| 7|  3  |     1      |  2019-12-25 |    0    |
| 8|  1  |     1      |  2019-12-20 |    0    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

PS. For the first record, since `sid 1` has 2 `IsAttend` before the first record, so it is 2 in `a_count`

How to use MySql to query this?

Thanks

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MySql version is v5.7.26

Comment: for row no.2, where id=2, sid=2, isattend=0, there was no similar data before the date.. how does it get a_count=1?

Comment: it has in row no.4, which is also sid=2 and isattend = 1, which means before row no.2, sid=2 has attended once, so the a_count in row.2 is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the example output was including of some other data. In this case you can do a `LEFT JOIN` to itself and perform `COUNT(*)` afterwards. Refer following example:

```
SELECT    a.id, a.sid, a.isattend, max(a.date),COUNT(b.date) 
FROM      mytable a 
LEFT JOIN mytable b 
ON        a.sid=b.sid 
AND       a.isattend=b.isattend 
AND       a.date > b.date 
GROUP BY  a.id, a.sid, a.isattend;
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT a.id, a.sid, a.isattend, max(a.date),ifnull(sum(b.isattend),0)
FROM mytable a 
LEFT JOIN mytable b 
ON a.sid=b.sid 
AND a.date > b.date GROUP BY a.id, a.sid, a.isattend;
```

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9kKmyHsSAMNk4BBPDWLHFh/5

Comment: seems your query cannot output row no.2 has a_count=1

Comment: How about row no.1, it has 3 record before the date whereby 2 of them isattend=1 and another one isattend=0. Shouldn't the first row restun count of 3 instead of 2?

Comment: @kt_at_kt , the value in isattend will always be 0 or 1 correct? If that the case, you can change the `COUNT()` to `SUM()` instead. And remove `a.isattend=b.isattend`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

So in your case you want that the count for the relevant *sid* id

if you want it in a different view query has to be
select sid from tablename 
count sid

then you will get reletive count for id

Comment: yes it is refer to the same `sid` I have edit my question, there should be `id` column in the table

Comment: sorry I don't quite get your answer, can you provide some sql so I can follow? Thanks

Comment: sid |count  query for this is select sid , count sid from tablename where isAttend>0 from this you get the sid and Attendence , try that out and please upvote my answer if you got something out of this thanks

Comment: Think it is not what I want. I need the attendance before the corresponding record, not total attendance